# Изменение тега

Tags: php

День добрый, есть например **Parser** в котором **{content}**

подменяется на текст в нашем случае это картинка:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

Необходимо выдернуть **путь** и сгенерировать что-то ввиде:

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg">
    <img src="script.php?src=/path/to/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

внимание, это надо сделать на уровне server'a т.е работать с переменно **{content}** а точнее **$data["content"]**. Идей уже нет с заказчик принудительно попросил пересадить его систему на ModX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$s = '<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />content content content<img src="trolololo/image.jpg" />content content content';
$s = preg_replace
( 
    '|<img\s+src=\"([^\"]+?)\"\s*/>|', 
    "<a href=\"$1\"><img src=\"script.php?src=$1\" /></a>",
    $s
);
print( $s );
```

Вывод:

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg"><img src="script.php?src=/path/to/image.jpg" />/a>content content content<a href="trolololo/image.jpg"><img src="script.php?src=trolololo/image.jpg" /></a>content content content
```

Comment: Да!!! Хорошо! Отлично! Но:

у меня еще есть width и height у картинки в исходном варианте. Сорри, что сразу не указал на это.

Comment: Я и так уже оказал медвежью услугу, сделав всю работу за вас. Попробуйте хоть что-то сделать самостоятельно, например, почитать [справочник по регекспам](http://citforum.ru/internet/perl/regexp/). А вот когда возникнут вопросы или сложности с прочитанным - обращайтесь, поможем.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @klopp . 1) Надо для начало почитать литературу, попробовать самому, потыкаться. 2) да и "задача" меняется слишком быстро: сначало просто выдернуть src, потом оказывается там есть текст после img который тоже надо выдернуть, потом появляется ширина с высотой и т.д.

Comment: Все бы ничего, но не поймите не правильно
1) это сложность того что ModX хотя работаю с фреймовраками
2) Заказчик торопит, было бы время читать и разбираться, разобрался бы)

Comment: Если вам не хочется или некогда разбираться - есть биржи фрилансеров.

Comment: @klopp хорошо, отлично, учту) так или иначе спасибо за помощь. Вся ночь с энергетиками впереди разобраться что и к чему =)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте регулярные выражения.

> preg_replace

например, что-то типо этого (код выдергивает src):

```
<?php
    $data='<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />';
    $images = array();
    preg_match_all('/(img|src)=("|\')[^"\'>]+/i', $data, $media);
    unset($data);
    $data = preg_replace('/(img|src)("|\'|="|=\')(.*)/i', "$3", $media[0]);

    //print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: Да вы просто капитан очевидности, я знаю что есть preg_replace, я само выражение построить не могу... просто так бы не спрашивал. Спасибо за внимание и понимание. ))

Comment: @Quiss, а как пробовали? 

P.S. И поясните, что мешает генерить правильный код в самом парсере,  "в котором {content} подменяется на текст". Вот и подменяйте на нужный текст там же.

Comment: Мешает в том что через tinymce modx'a загружается картинка и сразу сохраняется как <img src='' />...
на выходе нужно отдавать в другом виде. что-бы при этом при редактировании было все так-же <img src='' />.....

Comment: @Quiss пример скинул. возможно сделал слишком сложно, и можно было сделать это полегче )

Comment: @Quiss, я бы в этой ситуации приделывал не костыли, а свой плагин к TinyMCE на базе ImageDialog :)

Comment: @IVsevolod
$data = preg_replace('/(img|src)("|\'|="|=\')(.*)/i', "<a href='$3'><img src='?script.php?src=$3'></a>", $media[0]);

Помогло) спасибо)))

Comment: <?php
$data='<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />content content content<img src="trolololo/image.jpg" />content content content';
   
preg_match_all('/(img|src)=("|\')[^"\'>]+/i', $data, $media);
unset($data);
$data = preg_replace('/(img|src)("|\'|="|=\')(.*)/i', "<a href='$3'><img src='?script.php?src=$3'></a>", $media[0]);

print_r($data);
?>
Сделал так. Столкнулся с проблемой - скрипт выдергивает изображения, а контент удаляется.

Comment: @Quiss в таком случае лучше используйте вариант у klopp :), мой вариант всего лишь выдергивает путь.

> Необходимо выдернуть путь